# Integrating Images in a Docbook Manual in conjunction with phpDocumentor

Tags: php, documentation, docbook, phpdoc

is there a possibility to include images into a docbook manual compiled by phpDocumentor?

I tried both:

```
<mediaobject>
 <imageobject>
  <imagedata fileref="payment_flowchart.png" format="png"/> 
 </imageobject>
</mediaobject>
```

and:

```
<figure><title>foo</title>
 <graphic fileref="payment_flowchart.png"/>
</figure>
```

Then again the image paths I tried might not have been what phpDocumentor expected, but I don't know where to put them anyway really.

Maybe someone has tried it before and had more success?

**UPDATE**

Current non-working approach:

```
<refentry id="{@id}">
 <refnamediv>
  <refname>Company_Payment</refname>
 </refnamediv>
 <refsynopsisdiv>
  <author>
   Company
   <authorblurb>
    {@link mailto:my@mail.com André Hoffmann}
   </authorblurb>
  </author>
 </refsynopsisdiv>
 {@toc}
 <refsect1 id="{@id about}">
  <title>About</title>
  <para>
   text
   <imagedata fileref="/Users/andre/Zend/workspaces/DefaultWorkspace7/payment/doc/tutorials/company/payment_flowchart.png" format="PNG"/> 
  </para>
  <imagedata fileref="/Users/andre/Zend/workspaces/DefaultWorkspace7/payment/doc/tutorials/company/payment_flowchart.png" format="PNG"/> 
<mediaobject>
    <imageobject>
    <imagedata fileref="/Users/andre/Zend/workspaces/DefaultWorkspace7/payment/doc/tutorials/company/payment_flowchart.png" format="PNG"/> 
    </imageobject>
</mediaobject>
    <figure><title>foo</title>
        <graphic srccredit="Norman Walsh, 1998" fileref="/Users/andre/Zend/workspaces/DefaultWorkspace7/payment/doc/tutorials/company/payment_flowchart.png"/>
    </figure>
 </refsect1>
...
```

Comment: less than 24h to go..seems like no one ever wanted to have images in their phpdoc/docbook documentation :-(

Answer (score 0):

I think they fixed this in [1.3.0](http://phpdoc.org/news.php?id=52) using the `<graphic/>` tag. What version are you running?

Comment: I'm using version 1.4.1. The one that comes with Zend Studio for Eclipse 7.0

Comment: After looking at documentation for both it looks like you doing things correctly. I did notice that the format="png" had the png in uppercase like this: format="PNG" don't know if this make a difference.
http://www.docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/imageobject.html

Comment: I tried writing it in uppercase, but it doesn't show up either. Btw.: I also tried specifing an absolute path.

Comment: Could you try the imagedata tag without the wrapper tags? Wondering if there is some sort of conflict that way?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. I copied more or less the full source I'm using, so that you can see the context.

Comment: Don't know if this will help but I did find something:
http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/Smarty/plugins/_PEAR---PhpDocumentor---phpDocumentor---Smarty-2.6.0---libs---plugins---function.html_image.php.html

Comment: The link you posted is the API documentation of a smarty function that  creates HTML code for a image. I don't see how this could help me? As I can't use smarty in docbook.

Answer (score 0):

I had some success but only after I dropped the srccredit attribute. Wrapping the  tag in  with a  didn't make a bit of difference.

Simply:

```
<graphic fileref="/images/logo.png" />
```